# Comparing DateTime PHP in daylight saving time

Tags: php, date, datetime, compare

I was wondering if there's a way to handle daylight saving time comparison in DateTime

```
$timezone = "America/New_York";

$date1 = new DateTime('2021-11-07 01:55:00.000000', new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$date1->add(new DateInterval("PT5M"));
$date2 = new DateTime('2021-11-07 01:55:00.000000', new DateTimeZone($timezone));

/*
$date1 = 2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000
$date2 = 2021-11-07 01:55:00.000000
*/
var_dump($date1 > $date2);
/*
result: bool(true)
*/
```

Comment: Probably use or convert to UTC which doesn't observe Daylight Saving Time

Comment: Doing all your storage and maths in UTC and converting results to local time solves a lot of DST-related problems (including some PHP bugs), but it isn't always feasible (some times your local time needs to be the starting point).

Answer (score 0):

As we all know, DST switching introduces duplicate local times. If you move the clock 1 hour backwards at 2:00 then you'll have 1:00 twice on the same day. PHP is able to handle that and keeps track of which 1:00 it is. That's best illustrated with this other test case:

```
$timeZone = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');

$modified = new DateTime('2021-11-07 01:55:00.000000', $timeZone);
$modified->add(new DateInterval('PT5M'));
$raw = new DateTime('2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000', $timeZone);
var_dump($modified, $raw, $modified == $raw, $modified < $raw, $modified > $raw);

$control = new DateTime('2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000', $timeZone);
var_dump($raw, $raw, $control == $raw, $control < $raw, $control > $raw);
```

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(true)
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
object(DateTime)#3 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-11-07 01:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(16) "America/New_York"
}
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

If we set `1:55` and move forward, PHP knows the resulting time is the second `1:00`. If we set `1:00` directly, it assumes it's the first `1:00`—to be honest, it doesn't have a way to know which one you mean because geographical time zone identifiers pose this ambiguity. Even `var_dump()` is unable to display the difference.

On the other side, these duplicate `1:00`s are not really ambiguous because they belong to different time zones: `EDT` and `EST`. And that's the deal:

```
var_dump($modified->format('r T'), $raw->format('r T'), $control->format('r T'));
```

```
string(35) "Sun, 07 Nov 2021 01:00:00 -0500 EST"
string(35) "Sun, 07 Nov 2021 01:00:00 -0400 EDT"
string(35) "Sun, 07 Nov 2021 01:00:00 -0400 EDT"
```

In short, everything here works as expected. The only potential problem is when you need to set a time exactly at the DST boundary because you cannot use a geographical identifier due to its ambiguity. You'd need to specify `EST` or `EDT`, which is not as convenient and it isn't necessarily equivalent.

Comment: Thank you very much for you complete answer, I really need to set a time exactly at the DST so I might need to specify EST or EDT